# Присвоить год для даты dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, обработка-данных

Как присвоить столбцу датафрейму data, соответствие диапазанону годов 10 и 20 (data['10'],data['20']).
Например, 1900 - это начало - 1 год. 2000 - это тоже 1й год. Для диапозона 10, слеудующие года это 1910,1920,1930 или 2010,2020. Для диапозона в 20 лет - порядок = 1900,1920,1940...2000,2020

Данные:

```
data = pd.read_csv('test.csv', parse_dates=['Date'])

data['Date'],data['10'],data['20']

1959-07-21   9  19
1959-07-22   9  19
1959-07-23   9  19
1959-07-24   9  19
1959-07-27   9  19
1959-07-28   9  19
1959-07-29   9  19
1959-07-30   9  19
```

Пример для data['10']: 1990=0,1991=1,1992=2 ... ,1999=9

https://dropmefiles.com/UCFqV ссылка на файл

Comment: Ничего не понятно, но очень интересно...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я всё правильно понял, то можно использовать остаток от деления года по модулю (в Pandas есть всё):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.date_range('1900','2020', freq='Y')})
df['10'] = df.Date.dt.year.mod(10)
df['20'] = df.Date.dt.year.mod(20)
df
```

Вывод:

```
          Date 10  20
0   1900-12-31  0   0
1   1901-12-31  1   1
2   1902-12-31  2   2
3   1903-12-31  3   3
4   1904-12-31  4   4
... ... ... ...
115 2015-12-31  5   15
116 2016-12-31  6   16
117 2017-12-31  7   17
118 2018-12-31  8   18
119 2019-12-31  9   19
120 rows × 3 columns
```